# JMeter Connection Apache Server Refused

Tags: jmeter

I created jmeter test plan with 2000 threads and 10 ramp-up time.

When i ran the test against apache server, some of my test results give a connection refused error.

The connection refused error occured after 21 seconds.

So, my question is this 21 seconds originates from the jmeter or the apache web server?

As far as I know, apache server timeout default is 30 seconds, i didn't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your apache server is refusing connections, which means it could be overloaded or misconfigured.

Comment: so it's originated from the server, but i still confused why the connection refused exactly at 21 seconds.

Comment: it just got overloaded after 21 s and refused new connections.